# Compare the numbers in text file, if meets the condition run a shell script

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, numeric-data

I have a text file (created by a script) which contains only numbers in a single line like "5 17 42 2 87 33". I want to check every number with 50 (example), and if any of those numbers is greater than 50, I want to run another shell script. 
I'm using a vumeter program, my purpose is to run a sound recognition program if noise level is high. So I just want to determine a threshold.

Comment: Regex is probably not the best way to approach this. As long as you're dealing only with whole numbers (i.e., no ``17.42``), you can do the mathematical comparison directly in the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{ for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if($i > 50) { system("bash /other/shell/script.sh") } }' file.txt
```

Using a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=/path/to/file.txt

for num in $(<"$file"); do
    if ((num>50)); then
        bash /other/shell/script.sh
    fi
done
```

This will loop through each number in `file.txt` and check if that number is greater than 50, then run the script you provide.  However this may be an issue or unnecessary;  If there are multiple numbers in your text file greater than 50 should you run your script multiple times?

Comment: after if condition I added exit 1 command. It worked

Answer (score 1):

As a parameter-accepting function and `input` as the hard-coded filename:

```
greaterthan() (
  threshold=$1
  set -- $(< input)
  for arg
  do
    if [ "$arg" -gt "$threshold" ]
    then
      echo execute other shell script
      break
    fi
  done
)
```

Source that in, or make it a script, and call it like `greaterthan 50` or whatever number you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dc :

```
dc -f lefile -e '
  [ c                                         # clear the stack
  ! xmessage "a number is greater than 50" &  # pop up a message
  ] sr
  [ 50 <r                                     # if a number > 50 execute macro r
  z 0 <t                                      # if stack not empty execute macro t
  ] st
  lt x
'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the file into lines, then search for lines matching numbers greater than or equal to 50:

`fmt -w1 | egrep -q '(\d\d\d|[5-9]\d)(\..*)?' && sh other_script.sh`

The first parenthesized clause in regexp looks for at least three digits, or two digits starting with a '5'. The second clause allows an option decimal point and any suffix.

Use the `-q` option to suppress normal output, because we only want the exit status.